# What the meaning of $Pr(G = k|X = x)$ are liner in $x$?

Tags: probability

I am reading the Elements of Statistical Learning(ESL) but I am not understanding this sentence in chapter $4$ page $102$:

> >
>   Clearly, if either the $δ_k(x)$ or $Pr(G = k|X = x)$ are linear in $x$, then
>   the decision boundaries will be linear.

I am very thankful if somebody explains it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means the decision rule is linear. Say the discriminant function for class $k$ $\delta_k(x)$ is given by $f(x) = a+b^Tx$, and we assign a point to class $k$ if $f(x)>0$, then the decision boundary is clearly linear.

The authors demonstrated that this is also true for soft classification through log ratio $\log\frac{Pr(G = k|X = x)}{Pr(G = j|X = x)}$ in equation 4.1 and 4.2